# Computing inner products on tensor product of Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

Let $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ be Hilbert spaces with inner products $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_1$ and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_2$, respectively. As described in many references (and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces) as well), one can define a corresponding pre-Hilbert tensor product space by taking the (algebraic) tensor product $\mathcal{H}_1 \times \mathcal{H}_2$ equipped with the inner product
$$
  \langle x_1 \otimes x_2, y_1 \otimes y_2 \rangle \triangleq \langle x_1, y_1 \rangle_1 \langle x_2, y_2 \rangle_2
\quad \forall x_1,y_1 \in \mathcal{H}_1, \; x_2,y_2 \in \mathcal{H}_1,
$$
which extends bilinearly to *finite* linear combinations. The completion of this construction then yields a Hilbert space, which is a topological tensor product denoted by $\mathcal{H}_1 \hat{\otimes} \mathcal{H}_2$.

Now, my question regards the computation of the inner product for a given pair of tensors from $\mathcal{H}_1 \hat{\otimes} \mathcal{H}_2$. Let two arbitrary tensors in that space be
$$
  x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n \otimes v_n,
\quad \text{and} \quad 
  y = \sum_{n=1}^\infty w_n \otimes z_n.
$$
Now, the inner product was defined so as to extend bilinearly for *finite* linear combinations. Hence, how can one compute the inner product $\langle x, y \rangle$? Does it make sense to write
$$
 \langle x, y \rangle = 
\langle \sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n \otimes v_n, \sum_{m=1}^\infty w_m \otimes z_m \rangle
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \langle u_n \otimes v_n, w_m \otimes z_m \rangle,
$$
as if bilinearity holds also for infinite linear combinations?

Comment: Yes, of course, these things are constructed so that this kind of linear combinations are continuous operations. All necessary continuous estimates are supplied by Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Thank you @GiuseppeNegro for your comment. But could you please elaborate what do you mean by "all necessary continuous estimates"?

Comment: Anyway, let me add that there is nothing deep here, do not fear these things.

Comment: Okay, thanks in advance @GiuseppeNegro.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Hcal}{\mathcal{H}}$Your question boils down to the following.

> If $(h_1), (h_2)$ are sequences in $\Hcal_1, \Hcal_2$ respectively, is it true that 
>   $$\tag{1}
> h_1(n)\to h_1 \ \text{  and  }\ h_2(n)\to h_2\ \quad \Longrightarrow\quad h_1(n)\otimes h_2(n)\to h_1\otimes h_2?$$

Indeed, once (1) is proven, you can just apply it to the sequences
$$
h_1(n):=\sum_{k=1}^n u_k, \qquad h_2(n):=\sum_{k=1}^n v_k,$$ 
which you defined in the main text.

The proof of (1) is an immediate consequence of the obvious inequality 
$$
\lVert h_1\otimes h_2\rVert\le \lVert h_1\rVert\lVert h_2\rVert$$
(actually, this is even an *identity*), and of the bilinearity of $\otimes$.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not see exactly how this suffices. If h_1(n) and h_2(n) are defined as the partial sums like you did, then h_1(n) \otimes h_2(n) is going to be a sum of n^2 tensor products (with all cross-products), instead of a sum of tensor products u_k \otimes v_k (with same k) as I had written. Anyway, I wonder whether the answer to my question is yes simply because the scalar product defined for finite linear combinations of elementary tensors is continuous?